# Attaching files in signature by default on gmail

Tags: email, gmail

I notice that people sometimes send emails with their vcards attached. How are they doing this, and is there any way to do it on gmail?

Thanks SOCommunity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](http://vcardmaker.com/) will help you create a file - you just attach that to your email.

For corporate mail, this [Exchange signatures software](http://www.exclaimer.com/products/mail-disclaimers) can do it for all users.